# Bootstrap 4 Layout Issue Firefox OK / Chrome NOT

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

So, I have this part of code and it works perfectly fine in firefox but on chrome or opera the layout is completely broken, can anybody spot what am I doing wrong here?

```
<div class="row broadband-block">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 offset-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column broadband-main ">
        <div class="row pb-4 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start">
            <picture>
                <source media="(max-width: 576px)"
                        srcset="/img/broadband-icon@mob.png">
                <source media="(max-width: 1200px)"
                        srcset="/img/broadband-icon@med.png">
                <source media="(min-width: 1201px)"
                        srcset="/img/broadband-icon@1366.png">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="~/img/broadband-icon@1366.png" alt="broadband-icon">
            </picture>
            <h2 class="electricity-header">Broadband</h2>
        </div>

        <h3 class="electricity-title">We offer tailored Broadband solutions to suit your business needs</h3>
        <p class="electricity-text">
            We pride ourselves on the quality of our products and award-winning customer service. We understand how important
            the internet is to keep your business running smoothly. Benefit from high speed and consistently reliable connectivity
            with speeds of up to 24mb. Great value cost-effective business broadband with a range of packages designed to give
            you the flexibility to grow.<br /><br />

            Whether you are a sole trader, a small to medium business or a large organisation, we have the package to suit you.<br /><br />

            Not sure which solution is right for your business? Call one of our advisors
            today on <span class="voice-number-color">#######</span>
        </p>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start landing-page-buttons">
            <button type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="more-1" class="btn toggle-content voice-buttons">
                <span class="text">CONTACT US</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

/////////   CSS    /////////

```
.broadband-main {
    padding-top: 50px;

    @include for-phone {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `d-flex` causes the page (and the button) to display incorrectly on Chrome, but does not affect Firefox, Safari, and other browsers. By taking that out, the page now displays correctly on all browsers.

Here's the CSS:

```
.broadband-main {
    padding-top: 50px;

    @include for-phone {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row broadband-block container">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 offset-lg-3 justify-content-center flex-column broadband-main ">
        <div class="row pb-4 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start">
            <picture>
                <source media="(max-width: 576px)"
                        srcset="/img/broadband-icon@mob.png">
                <source media="(max-width: 1200px)"
                        srcset="/img/broadband-icon@med.png">
                <source media="(min-width: 1201px)"
                        srcset="/img/broadband-icon@1366.png">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="~/img/broadband-icon@1366.png" alt="broadband-icon">
            </picture>
            <h2 class="electricity-header">Broadband</h2>
        </div>

        <h3 class="electricity-title">We offer tailored Broadband solutions to suit your business needs</h3>
        <p class="electricity-text">
            We pride ourselves on the quality of our products and award-winning customer service. We understand how important
            the internet is to keep your business running smoothly. Benefit from high speed and consistently reliable connectivity
            with speeds of up to 24mb. Great value cost-effective business broadband with a range of packages designed to give
            you the flexibility to grow.<br /><br />

            Whether you are a sole trader, a small to medium business or a large organisation, we have the package to suit you.<br /><br />

            Not sure which solution is right for your business? Call one of our advisors
            today on <span class="voice-number-color">#######</span>
        </p>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start landing-page-buttons">
            <button type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="more-1" class="btn toggle-content voice-buttons">
                <span class="text">CONTACT US</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the help but that wasn't the case. I found out that having a button in a separate div with bootstrap classes was breaking the layout on other browsers for some reason. I centered the button on mobile by using custom CSS rather and completely removed the div around it.